# Eclipse Oxygen Installer unable to locate companion shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, development-environment

I get an error trying to install Eclipse 4.7 (Oxygen) Oracle Corporation using the installer program,  eclipse-inst-win64.exe Am I missing a system variable? Am I missing a prerequisite? This computer is locked down pretty tight. However I am installing by running as an administer.

First I installed the Oracle JDK 8.162 64-bit - No problems

Then I ran the eclipse-inst-win64.exe installer and quickly got the following error:
The Eclipse Installer executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

I thought this could be just that the program did not know where the JDK was installed. The JDK installer does not set any environment variables except for adding the path to the JDK to the PATH variable. So I searched StackOverflow for a list of JDK variables to add. I added the following new *system* variables:

- CLASSPATH = .;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162
- JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
- JDK_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%
- JRE_HOME = %JAVA_HOME%\jre

I modified the Path variable to put the bin directory first:
PATH = %JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows… rest of the existing path variable

I ran the eclipse-inst-win64.exe installer again and got the same error:

I rebooted but still got this error. 
I tried to "run as administrator" but got the same error.

Some people suggest that the path can get too long with the default installation directory so I tried installing the JDK in C:\JDK\ but still got the same problem.

Java seems to be installed properly:

H:>java -version

java version "1.8.0_162"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

I still assume that I made a mistake with my system variables or my JDK installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed the "companion shared library" was inside the JDK installation. I extracted the installation files to another directory (C:\eclipse) and then it ran. The "companion shared library" must have been inside the zipped installer. I fixated on the idea that the problem had to be a failure to connect to the JDK that I did not consider any other possibilities. It is installed now.